# Проверить может ли массив быть "сбалансированным"

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Задание  следующее:
Создать метод, проверяющий, может ли массив быть "сбалансированным", т.е. разделённым на две части в каком-то месте, таким образом, чтобы сумма элементов одной части равнялась сумме элементов второй. Например:

```
{ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 }; // true
{ 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3 }; // false
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 4 }; // true
```

У меня  получился  вот  такой  код:

```
public class Task {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("The result is: " + isBalanced(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3}));
    }
    public static boolean isBalanced(int[] a) {
        boolean status = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if(a[i] + a[j] != 0) {
                    status = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    status = false;
                }

            }
            if(!status) {
                status =  false;
                break;
            }

        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

При компиляции все три варианта выдают `true`. Как мне  написать  код так, чтобы при этом второй вариант выдавал `false`.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте следующий код:

```
public static boolean isBalanced(int[] input) {
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        int balance = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            balance += input[j];
        }

        for(int j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
            balance -= input[j];
        }

        if(balance == 0) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Я бы чуть-чуть модифицировал: 1) сделал бы вместо `before` и `after` одну переменную `balance` и просто бы прибавлял левую часть и отнимал правую. 2) чтобы избежать лишних проверок `if(j <= i)` сделал бы 2 цикла `for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) balance++;` и `for (int j = i+1; j <= input.length; j++) balance--;`

Comment: @Андрей инкремент с декрементом не подойдут, а остальное сейчас исправлю

Comment: Спасибо большое  за  помощь

Comment: @Vit если вы уже где-то использовали этот код, то замените там `j = 0` во 2-ом цикле на `j = i + 1`.

Comment: @wcobalt я погорячился c этим) в общем мою идею вы поняли)

Comment: @wcobalt внесите правку для первого цикла: `for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            balance += input[j];
        }` и для второго цикла: `for(int j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
            balance -= input[j];
        }`

Comment: @Vit обновите весь код.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko спасибо за правки.